# GraphQL Syntax Error while passing parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

When I try to pass this query, I get a syntax error on the first line even though I am using a mutation with the same syntax that works:

```
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }
```

```
interface WhereInput {
  email_contains: String;
}

export const LoadUsersQuery = gql`
query usersList($where: WhereInput) {
    users(where: $where}) {
      nodes {
        email
        firstName
      }
      totalCount
    }
}
```

The word `usersList`is self-defined.

This is the original query looks like on the playground:

```
query {
    users(where: {email_contains: "B"}) {
      nodes {
        email
        firstName
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
```

And this is how I am calling it:

```
const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState('');
```

```
  const [loadUsers, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery);
```

```
return (
    <div>
        <StyledSearchBar
          value={searchItem}
          onChange={value => {
            setSearchItem(value);
          }}
           onRequestSearch={() => loadUsers({
             variables: {
               where: {email_contains: searchItem}
             }
           })}

        />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: what is `searchItem`? ... check hardcoded value first ... define some `$vars` object first in `onRequestSearch` body, check it's defined properly, pass into `variables`, check network requests, etc.

Comment: searchItem is the value I'm reading from the searchbar. I have printed and tested and it works. The query gives a syntax error. It is never executed so it never gets to the network requests part @xadm

Comment: syntax pointing to .... ?

Comment: Please always post the exact error message when you are getting an error.

Comment: next time test in playground using variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is correct (and should point you to the exact location of the problem) - there's a stray `}` in there:

```
users(where: $where}) {
#                  ^
```